# Running application in a multithreaded environment

Tags: java

In the application,a heavy file is being loaded in a function. If multiple threads try calling the same
function, then the application crashes due to multiple objects being created and multiple threads loading the same file. If a single thread calls the function, then the application becomes slow as each thread is waiting for the previous thread to be completed. Suggestions for a good approach to mitigate this issue !

Comment: You need to thread pool with a size carefully thought of. Please post some sample code.

Comment: i do not have any sample code as of now :)

Comment: Then your question is out of topic :)

Comment: You need to provide specific details to get a worthy Answer. What is a "heavy" file; do you mean large? If "large", how big do you mean? What kind of data? Is the entire file being read and parsed into a collection of objects? Is the entire set of data meant to be kept in memory during the execution of your app? So is your problem really about how to hold off queries until the data is loaded into RAM? Is the file read-only, or changing? Have you considered using a database? If so, what rules out its use?

Answer (score 0):

Your code is lacking synchronization. Usually you have one UI thread for user interaction and N worker threads. File loading function should be called only by worker thread and you have to prevent other worker threads from accessing function if loading process started already.

Consider using:

- Java Synchronize
- https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReentrantLock.html
- Atomic objects
- RxJava - could be used here to simplify threading but

With above you can implement two strategies:

1. prevent any function call if function is running already
2. wait for previous execution to complete and then block&execute
   it doesn't solve synchronization problem by default.

I think you need to do 1. - why load same file multiple times?

```
class FileLoader {

  private boolean isFileLoaded = false

  @WorkerThread
  public synchronized void loadFilePseudoCode() {
     if(isFileLoaded) return;
     if(startFileLoading()) isFileLoaded = true;
  }
}
```

You need to make sure that isFileLoaded is written only inside synchronized function. In code above function is synchronized by class instance.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely your application crashes due to **OutOfMemory**. 
If several threads load large files into the application.

In blind (without code and example),i can advice the following:

1. The increase of -xmx
2. Use NIO to process the file
3. You can yourself, instead of NIO, load the file into native memory
4. Make a cache for the function and save the cached file locally on the application

Comment: thanx...it helped...it was a design discussion.